# Target Deploy for Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to set a target deploy for Firebase Functions.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/targets

This is the firebase.json file

```
{
  "functions": [{
    "target": "production",
    "source": "src/prod/functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }]
}
```

The predeploy runs normally but when deploying gets an error

```
functions[prod]: Finished running predeploy script.
Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
```

If I go to firebase-debug.log it shows:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
```

Putting the Functions folder on the project root it will deploy normally.

What is missing here?

Comment: The documentation states that "Firebase supports deploy targets for: Firebase Hosting sites, Cloud Storage for Firebase storage buckets, Firebase Realtime Database instances"

Answer (score 1):

From the link that you posted:

> Firebase supports deploy targets for:
>
> - Firebase Hosting sites
> - Cloud Storage for Firebase storage buckets
> - Firebase Realtime Database instances

I was also looking for the same answer, but it seems that it is still not supported in the end of 2022

Answer (score 0):

Try running `firebase init` and set the options as best you can so it doesn't overwrite your existing project. I had to run it from the parent directory of `/functions` otherwise it will create a new directory but maybe there is some option to set a different directory name to suit your case.